# Поиск, сборка и компиляция всех scss файлов в css

Tags: webpack, scss

На одном проекте видел, как gulp искал все scss в проекте и компилировал их в один css. Причем, файлы между собой связаны не были, т.е. не использовались `@import` внутри scss.
Вопрос: можно ли / как настроит webpack, чтобы он делал то же самое, причем в файлах не писать require, а просто в index.html подключить один "style.css"?

Answer (score 0):

Вообще, для этого вам не нужен webpack и он так не работает. Просто воспользуйтесь транслятором scss. Он вам нужен в любом случае. А также, тем или иным скриптом для автоматизации сборки. Для запуска как транслятора, так и webpack, используйте npm scripts. Также, API транслятора можно инициировать из webpack.config.js.

Но можно сделать это с помощью [Webpack Extract Text Plugin](https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin) и вот такого `style.js` в индексе:

```
(function (requireContext) {
    return requireContext.keys().map(requireContext);
} (require.context('../', true, /(\.scss$)|(\.css$)/)));
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую попозже ))